# Accessing properties of iterated values in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am looping through a list like so:

```
  <li v-for="item in filteredParentItems"
      v-if="item.action === 'list'"
      v-on:click="getNextPath"
      v-bind:data-next-path="item.nextPath"
      v-bind:data-action="item.action"
      v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"
      class="item">
        {{item.name}}
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
```

In order to tell if the item is active, I run isActive, a computed function to tell if the path is equal to the breadcrumb path I have in my Vuex store:

```
  computed: {
    isActive () {
      return this.nextPath === this.$store.state._breadcrumbPath;
    }
  }
```

The issue is I don't have access to item.nextPath within the computed function because I don't have the li set up as its own component.  Is there a way to pass the actual item into the isActive function to grab its property?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to pass values into a computed property. Instead, you could change `isActive` to a method, and then pass in `item`.

In the `li`:

```
v-bind:class="{ active: isActive(item) }"
```

Then change `isActive` to a method and operate on the specific item:

```
methods: {
  isActive (item) {
    return item.nextPath === this.$store.state._breadcrumbPath;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am going to give this a shot now.

Answer (score -1):

you'll need to do this within your class binding:

```
<li v-for="item in filteredParentItems"
  v-if="item.action === 'list'"
  v-on:click="getNextPath"
  v-bind:data-next-path="item.nextPath"
  v-bind:data-action="item.action"
  v-bind:class="{ active: item.nextPath === _breadcrumbPath }"
  class="item">
    {{item.name}}
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

then in your components script:

```
computed: {

  _breadcrumbPath () {
    this.$store.state._breadcrumbPath
  },
  ...
```